# Exchange 2007 Email Address Policies

Tags: exchange-2007

We have recently upgraded to Exchange 2007 (from 2003) and have noticed the change from recipient policies to email address policies.  We have two separate domains (let's call them domaina.com and domainb.com) we receive email for, have email address policies and both email address policies are not applied.  In our Exchange 2003 environment, domaina.com was the default email address when we created new mailboxes and due to the migration, domainb is the default (and its email address policy is a higher priority).  Now, when we create a new mailbox (or edit existing ones), the primary email address becomes domainb.com.

Now the question is, is this as simple as putting the email address policies in the correct order?  Do I have to apply both policies?  What effect will the above changes make to existing mailboxes?  Since we do not have any conditions set on the policies, I assume prior to making these changes, I should force all domainb mailboxes to not automatically update email address based on policy?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/managing-email-address-policies.html
Above may help, You must have at least two EAPs aside from the default in order to see the Change Priority Action pane option

Answer (score 1):

Well, the recommended practice from Microsoft is to have your default e-mail address policy contain only your internal AD domain (company.local) and then create separate e-mail address policies to target your mailboxes accordingly - for example with OU's.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the default mail domain this will affect the policy.  If you do not want this to happen then make sure that you untick the update email based on policy and this will allow you to select manually for a mailbox which to have as their main email.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the automatically update based on policy option and just wanted to confirm that the next steps should be to uncheck the mailboxes I don't want to change, prioritize the policies, and apply them both correct?